# Saving is making "\n" go on a new line in c++ in my code on vscode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

So I have a program that's unsaved and here is what it looks like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<string> msg{"Hello", "C++", "World", "from", "VS Code", "and the C++ extension!"};

    for (const string& word : msg) {
        cout << word << " ";
    }
    cout << '\n';
    cout << "Hello world" << "\n";
}
```

Once I save it this is what happens

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<string> msg{"Hello", "C++", "World", "from", "VS Code", "and the C++ extension!"};

    for (const string& word : msg) {
        cout << word << " ";
    }
    cout << '\n';
    cout << "Hello world"
         << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The only style that I know that I have applied so far is Google style guide and this worked earlier in the day but now it's doing this. I'm also getting this error `first.cpp:8:23: error: expected ';' at end of declaration vector<string> msg{"Hello", "C++", "World", "from", "VS Code", "and the C++ extension!"};`

Comment: why don't you put the `\n` in the `Hello World` string

Comment: What if I had an in integer operation like 7 + 5 instead?

Comment: if you don't want to disable the formatter (a recommendation) than tweak the settings to get what you want

Answer (score -2):

Try to use just << endl instead of "\n"

Comment: You should elaborate on your solution, this seems like it's just a comment/suggestion and not an answer that addresses the root of OP's problem.